# set color in ng-datepicker

Tags: css, angular, datepicker

I want to set the background color of the active date. The default value is blue and I want to set it green. Any idea how I can achieve that?

I use the datepicker below:

[Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker)

[image]

This is my code:

html:

```
 <ng-datepicker [options]=option [(ngModel)]="date"></ng-datepicker>
```

ts:

```
 this.option = {
  minYear: 1970,
  maxYear: 2050,
  displayFormat: 'MM.DD.YYYY',
  barTitleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
  dayNamesFormat: 'dd',
  firstCalendarDay: 1, // 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday
  locale: deLocale,
  //minDate: new Date(Date.now()), // Minimal selectable date
  //maxDate: new Date(Date.now()),  // Maximal selectable date
  barTitleIfEmpty: 'Wähle ein Datum aus',
  placeholder: 'Wähle ein Datum aus', // HTML input placeholder attribute (default: '')
  addStyle: {
  }, // Optional, value to pass to [ngStyle] on the input field
  fieldId: 'my-date-picker', // ID to assign to the input field. Defaults to datepicker-<counter>
  useEmptyBarTitle: false, // Defaults to true. If set to false then barTitleIfEmpty will be disregarded and a date will always be shown 
};
```

Comment: Add a relevant code snippet in the question. This is way too broad and unclear. I mean we can't see your code how can we know what is wrong without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to your component's CSS would make the current day have a green background

```
span.day-unit.is-today.is-selected {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```